# Jquery data() storing multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple app with a few multi-select lists.  I need to store the selections from these lists so that I can use them later in calculations.
Since there isn't a whole lot of data being stored I thought I would use jquery's data().
I have used it many times to store single values but can't get the right syntax to store multiple selections.
Can I use something like the following to save these values or will it erase the previous value on each loop?

```
function storeCheckBoxes($this) {
//save a list of checkbox values
   var key;
   $("input:checkbox").each(function () {

       if ($this.is(":checked")) {
           key = $this.attr("id");
           value = $this.val();
           $("#services").data(key, value);

       }
   });
}
```

How can I store multiple items to a single dom element?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using the same `key` and `value` on every iteration.

I think you're confusing `$this` with `$(this)`. `$this` refers to the element you're passing to the `storeCheckBoxes` function, so you're setting the same data attributes over and over again by using `$this.val()`.

You probably want to get the data from the checkboxes themselves, so you'll want to use `$(this)` inside your `.each` loop. `$(this)` inside your `.each` loop refers to the checkbox, not the original element that was passed to `storeCheckBoxes()`.

Also, as you're using the checkbox's ID as the `key`, you'll want to make sure that each checkbox has a unique ID as well.

```
function storeCheckBoxes($this) {
// save a list of checkbox values
   $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
       if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
           var key = $(this).attr("id");
           var value = $(this).val();
           $("#services").data(key, value);

       }
   });
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: @SheriTrager no worries!

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your question you wan't to store `key` and `value` in different `data-attributes`.

What you are doing

```
$("#services").data(key, value);
```

suppose:-

```
key='a' and value= 12 and services is a div
```

it will add a `data-attribute` which has a value 12 and can be retrieved using key `'a'` like bellow.

```
$("#services").data('a'); will give you 12
```

If you want to insert multiple `data-attributes` you have to set the `data` attribute for each item once.

Like bellow

```
$("#services").data('key', key);
$("#services").data('value', value);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1L4Lhsp1/2/)